# How does Python's pycrypto library generate primes?

Tags: prime-numbers

The pycrypto library in Python can generate random n-bit prime numbers. The syntax I use is as follows:

```
from Crypto.Util import number
number.getPrime(2048)
```

The above function has a very impressive performance and returns primes with a very small delay. **What is the process used to generate such large primes in such short time periods in this function?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation is not directly telling the implemented algorithm. One can check from the source [code](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Util/number.py). `getPrime` uses `isPrime` and that calls the [Rabin-Miller Primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test).

- `getPrime` generates a random odd number $\texttt{N}$ and calls `isPrime`

  ```
  number=getRandomNBitInteger(N, randfunc) | 1
       while (not isPrime(number, randfunc=randfunc)):
           number=number+2
  ```
- `isPrime` first checks for evenness and for pre-calculated Sieve primes, that list is the first 10000 primes. It may be a prime in the Sieve or divisible by one of them. If none of the cases, then the Rabin-Miller test is performed.

**The Probability:** The returned value of `getPrime`, if a probable prime, then the probability is given by
$$ 1 - \frac{1}{4^k}$$ where $k$ is the number of iterations.

**The Number of iterations:** The Library defines

```
false_positive_prob=1e-6
```

calculates the $k$ by

```
k = int(math.ceil(-math.log(false_positive_prob)/math.log(4)))
```

and from this, the number of iteration in the library is $k=10$.

Note that In my undergraduate, we used $k=20$. That makes false positive in the worst case `1e-12` where the library has `1e-6`.

**The Complexity:** If modular exponentiation by repeated squaring is used then the complexity is $\mathcal{O}(k \log^3 n)$ where $k$ is the number of iterations to test that determines the probability.

Comment: This answer feels slightly incomplete. It doesn't mention what `isPrime` gets run on in the first place (a randomly sampled $n$ bit number).

Comment: This generates a prime with a bias: the probability of a prime being selected grows linearly with how far above the previous prime it is.

Comment: @fgrieu this is due to the library's design or Rabin-Miller?

Comment: @kelalaka: this is due to moving to the next candidate prime with `number=number+2`, rather than drawing a new random number, or moving to the next one with a more sophisticated procedure.

Comment: @fgrieu assuming that getPrime succeeds after considering a relatively small number of candidates (say, no more than 10^100) it means the process selects a prime from the region between a truly random x and x+2*10^100. For 2048 bit numbers, that's pretty much a uniform distribution, as the relative bias is 2*10^100 / 2^2048 ≈ 10^-516 ≈ 0.   A much more serious issue is the 10^-6 possibility of false positives.

Comment: @Peteris: The spacing of primes around $p$ is in the order of $\log(p)$, thus the number of candidates tested for a 2048-bit prime is usually in the hundreds, rarely many thousands. I'm not saying that the bias endangers the safety of the key. My point is that it is detectable with a moderate number of private keys (and I'm wondering for public keys).

Comment: I think it's more important to ask how the witness number is generated in `isPrime`. If it is generated in a predictable way, then it would be possible to construct composite numbers that fail many Miller-Rabin tests.

Comment: @forest The library lets you choose the random function if not supplied `Random.new()` is used. Line 175 at the [source](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Util/number.py)

Comment: 1e-6 is a _worst case_ probability that `isPrime` yields true for _any fixed_ composite integer, and is a fair estimate for a Carmichael number. However these get vanishingly rare when moving to large ones, and for other composites the probability that `isPrime` yields true is much lower, and tends to decreases when the number gets larger. Therefore the probability that `getPrime` returns a composite is much lower than 1e-6 (which would be perfectly detectable, and a serious issue).